Fire VDB is coming from everywhere!

It's quite obvious in the image, that the fire is supposed to be only in the middle of the render, but it's spreading out everywhere, the fire behind is not supposed to be there. I have no idea. It's an imported VBD sequence. What am I missing out? One is in render, and the other is in preview, the preview version is okay, but the final is not. There aren't any plugins involved, just VDB.


This was such a silly mistake and an easy fix, my VDB was in a collection that the particle system was using, to scatter meshes around. After a few hours, I realized where I did wrong, I just glanced at the outline and saw the issue.
